# Navigation menu with subMenu centered using position not working

Tags: html, css

I did menu navigation which on the top of the website. The navigation menu has its sublink as well. I have tried many position styles like `absolute`, `inline-block`, `inline`, `text-align:center`. Still they are not working. The following code below:

HTML

```
<div class="navigationMenu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#"> LINK 1 </a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"> LINK 2 </a>
        <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 2 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"> LINK 3 </a>
        <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 2 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> LINK 4 </a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navigationMenu {clear:both;text-align:center;margin-top:10px;}
.navigationMenu ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;position: absolute;text-align: center;}
.navigationMenu li {display:inline;float:left;margin-right: 1px;text-align: center;}
.navigationMenu li a {min-width:140px;height: 50px;text-align: center;line-height: 50px;color: #fff;background:#B22222;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;}
.navigationMenu li:hover a {background: #19c589;}
.navigationMenu li:hover ul a {background: #f3f3f3;color: #2f3036;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;}
.navigationMenu li:hover ul a:hover {background: #19c589;color: #fff;}
.navigationMenu li ul {display: none;position: absolute;}
.navigationMenu li ul li {display: block;float: none;}
.navigationMenu li ul li a {width: auto;min-width: 100px;padding: 0 20px;}
.navigationMenu ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {display: block;}
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/xtshL3zw/) The problem is I can't make the menu to the centered of `.navigationMenu`. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI You can use the inbuilt code snippet option to create a demo...

Comment: I see, I have created JSFiddle thou..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once set the `<li>`'s display to `inline-block` and remove the unnecessary positioning and `floats`, you can use `margin: 0 auto` to horizontally center align the `<ul>` as shown below:

```css
.navigationMenu {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.navigationMenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigationMenu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigationMenu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #B22222;
}
.navigationMenu li:hover a {
  background: #19c589;
}
.navigationMenu li:hover ul a {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #2f3036;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.navigationMenu li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}
.navigationMenu li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.navigationMenu li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
.navigationMenu li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.navigationMenu ul li a:hover + .hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationMenu">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#"> LINK 1 </a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> LINK 2 </a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 2 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> LINK 3 </a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> SUB LINK 2 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> LINK 4 </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Side note: Some CSS properties like `text-align` are inherited, you don't have to specify the same for child elements unless you want to override it. So I've cleaned up a bit by removing them.

Comment: I seee.. Thanks mate! This is the one I'm looking for!

Comment: Anyway, I just noticed that you changed my coding a little bit? Would you mind to let me know what did you change? Thanks

Comment: Never mind. I just did it. I have removed `float:left;`. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: @Anthosiast Sorry, For some reason I'm not getting any notifications without refreshing the pages. I like the responsiveness of your menu, nice work..!

Comment: No problem, you did it very well thou! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option available to you:

```
.navigationMenu ul {
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried it using Jsfiddle? I tried that and it doesn't work at all. @ralph.m

Comment: @Anthosiast, is that [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xtshL3zw/2/) what are you looking for?

Comment: @olgacosta yes this is the one I am looking for. But the submenu is really messy.